# Ошибка при экспорте в апк Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Вот build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.lgl.modmenu"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
        }
    }
    ndkVersion = '21.3.6528147'
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
        gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
    }
}
```

И полный стек ошибки

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libCumMachine.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

Comment: Проверьте или покажите `Android.mk` - может быть там она дублируется.

Comment: Android.mk не дублируется но я заметил что это https://imgur.com/a/066rcIC

Comment: Да не сам файл `Android.mk` дублируется, а записи модулей или зависимостей в нём. На картинке я не вижу ничего необычного: две библиотеки собраны для трёх архитектур, в соответствии с `abiFilters`

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю об этом но если что вот паастбин https://pastebin.com/wykhxg9T

Comment: Синхронизацию, ребилд, сброс кеша - всё это уже пробовали?